# Split String with semicolon token in JAVA

Tags: java, split, stringtokenizer

I'm having issues trying to split a String whith semicolon :

String is :

dsnSalarie;e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4; ;S21.G00.30.008;e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4;**;**;

The bolted semicolon is a token and must not be considered as a delimiter, so I've tried to change the delimite for a String like "<;>" :

dsnSalarie<;>e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4<;> <;>S21.G00.30.008<;>e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4<;>;<;>

With StringUtils.split or with StringTokenizer I can't get that semicolon, even when using "StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens"

The only work around that i found is by surrounder the semicolon whith space, and them trim it when splited :

dsnSalarie<;>e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4<;> <;>S21.G00.30.008<;>e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4<;> ; <;>

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: I think you'll have to add the java-tag to your Question. Also, can you post the code where you split them, so we can see the examples? With their respective output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand, but the following code:

```java
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test="dsnSalarie<;>e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4<;> <;>S21.G00.30.008<;>e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4<;>;<;>";
    String[] split = test.split("<;>");
    for (String string : split) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
}
```

Yields

```
dsnSalarie
e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4
 
S21.G00.30.008
e3f5c7c0-5f5e-4579-a262-3fd87aafe1e4
;
```

A tokenizer is not able to differentiate between same characters, like the semicolon. If there is a semantic attached to the ; you need a proper parser like ANTLR to formulate your language which can infer higher order from the tokens.

Comment: I was using StringUtils.split() which doesnt work, with String.split() it's all fine ! Thanks ! (I edited my post for correction)